# Google Sheets Tick Box Query

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I've been developing a spreadsheet over the last few months and I've been able to solve most issues through online searches, particularly through this site. However, I've come up against one that I'm struggling with so thought I'd see if anyone can help. An example of my issue is below:

I have a tick box in A1 and B1 and the total of ticked boxes in C1. The issue I have is that I want the total in C1 to be "1" whether A1 is the only box ticked, B1 is the only box ticked or both boxes in A1 and B1 are ticked. If both boxes are unchecked then the value in C1 should be 0.

I hope this example makes sense and would appreciate any help with finding the right formula for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming checkbox values are `TRUE` / `FALSE`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A&B1:B), IF((N(A1:A))+(N(B1:B))>0, 1, 0), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi player0, thanks for your response. However I've realised that by trying to simplify my question and thinking I'd be able to just change the formula to suit the cells I'm using, I've actually taken you down the wrong avenue - apologies for that. Im finding it hard to explaon but I'll try again using the cells I'm using. I have checkboxes in F9:F71 which are totalled (when checked) in B2. I also have checkboxes in K9:K71 which I want to be counted in B2 but as an either/or with those in F column not on top of these - so the total should never exceed 63

Comment: So as an example if we assume no boxes are checked and I tick F9 or K9 or both, B2 would only read 1. Hope this makes sense as I'm confusing myself haha

Comment: I see (I guess)... you need this in **B2**: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(LEN(F9:F71&K9:K71 ), IF((N(F9:F71))+(N(K9:K71 ))>0, 1, 0), )))`

Comment: and if you want to add limiter (63) then use this in **B2**: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SUM(IF((N(F9:F71))+(N(K9:K71))>0, 1, 0))>63, "error", SUM(IF((N(F9:F71))+(N(K9:K71))>0, 1, 0))))`

Comment: player0, firstly I apologise that it's taken me a month to get back to you - life took me away from my little spreadsheet project unfortunately. I can now confirm that I have finally tested your new array formula and it has worked a treat - I will put it fully into practice over the coming days as I've only tested it on my master sheet so far but it appears to be a fantastic addition to my spreadsheet. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: your formula posted Sep 5 at 21:15 is working fine but I'm now wanting to develop it slightly so that if the information in ```B9:B71``` reads "Scrapped" this is not calculated in the formula. In other formulas that I've required certain information to be omitted I've used <> but will this work within your array formula above?